# is it good to use Wordpress in the same url extension in terms of seo?

Tags: seo

i have got a website and i want to add a Wordpress blog to it for additional (fresh) content and of course, better SEO. i'm new to Wordpress but i found out that the pages created by it are stored in the database so it's almost impossible to link to any of those pages, so it's confusing for me because i don't know that when Google crawls my domain will it also crawl database-stored wordpress pages and if it does, is this any good for SEO ranking of my whole site?

i just wanna know using the wordpress blog like "www.website.com/en/blog" will have the same SEO impact as making a blog using Dreamweaver, which has separate HTML pages that can be linked to. (apart from marking-up content)

Thanks

Comment: "...will have the same SEO impact as making a blog using Dreamweaver". Yes. Your content will be far more important than your method of publishing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that WordPress stores your page/post content in a database.  Every CMS does this, however.  Googlebot crawls links so it will see the public or front-end version of the page that WordPress produces at each URL.  WordPress will serve up the page content from the database along with the theme/template/css rules in effect on that page.

Bottom line: how you see the final output of your WordPress pages is how Google will crawl them, essentially.  Googlebot is not using a browser, for example so it interprets your page differently.

Name your posts with good, descriptive titles and personally I would recommend using the "post name" style for Permalinks.  This gives you good keyword-rich URLs.

WP admin  > Settings  > Permalinks

WordPress is very SEO friendly right out of the box and on-page SEO is a breeze.

Comment: thank you but i can't vote up your answer. so with all that seo friendliness of WP, having it as a blog on same directory of my website will increase its PR. right?

Comment: Yes - absolutely.  Google loves quality content and rewards sites that produce new content relative to those that do not.

Comment: Awesome, sorry for my silly questions about seo and that kinda stuff. just to check if i got that right, the reason why this increases my main website's PR is that the WP blog is in the same domain (and directory) as the main site, if, for example it was in a sub-domain that wouldn't be any good for the main site. am i right?

Comment: Correct.  It has been my experience that subdomains are treated as completely separate sites.  Content in subfolders benefits the parent domain, while content in subdomains does not appear to.

Answer (score 0):

The database is irrelevant as far as front end in concerned. It's just an implementation detail.

WP makes your posts/pages available at their individual URLs and has additional URLs for archives (and more). There is absolutely nothing preventing from linking to the URLs, that's what they are for.